# Can I somehow just print a line of code using a macro in Haxe, adding it to the stats, for FFun?

Tags: build, macros, haxe

I have already spent a lot of time trying to do this, but it gives a very strange error, moreover, printing the very goal of what I want. It looks very funny.

I read quite a lot about reification, but there is no answer to my question.

states.push(macro $p{["this", f.name]} = $i{"components.get_table(" + t + ");"});

src/Main.hx:31: lines 31-83 : Defined in this class
src/ecs/macro_tools/ProcessorInject.hx:54: characters 53-89 : Unknown identifier : components.get_table(ecs.components.Transform);

or output:
src/ecs/macro_tools/ProcessorInject.hx:54: characters 53-89 : Unknown identifier : components.get_table(ecs.components.Transform);
src/Main.hx:31: lines 31-83 : Defined in this class
src/ecs/macro_tools/ProcessorInject.hx:54: characters 53-89 : Unknown identifier : components.get_table(ecs.components.Circle);
src/Main.hx:31: lines 31-83 : Defined in this class
Build halted with errors (haxe.exe).

Comment: It's hard to know what's going on with so little context, but `states.push(macro $p{["this", f.name]} = components.get_table($v{t}));` should work better.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a meta build, I tried to pass statically components using Any, but it also did not work.
`code
//...
@:build(ecs.macro_tools.ProcessorInject.build(ProcessorA.ccomponents))
//...
macro static public function build(components:Any):Array<Field> {
states.push(macro $p{["this", f.name]} = components.get_table($v{t}));

File "_build/src/typing/macroContext.ml", line 670, characters 11-17: Assertion failed`

Comment: ```code var st:String = f.name + " = components.get_table(" + t.toString() + ")";
var e = Context.parse(st, Context.currentPos());
states.push(macro $e);```
Decided and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
var st:String = f.name + " = components.get_table(" + t.toString() + ")"; 
var e = Context.parse(st, Context.currentPos()); 
states.push(macro $e);
```

Decided and it worked!